# Can a GPT Hard Drive Read MBR Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, gpt

So, here is my problem:
I installed Windows 8.1 Pro on a UEFI/GPT HDD (hdd0). I've been using my computer for a while and it turns out that it's running out of free space. 
Is it possible to create a partition on another HDD (hdd1, which is MBR) and then storing all additional files and program there?

The schema will be:

```
hdd0 (GPT): Windows 8.1, software, documents, etc...
hdd1 (MBR): music, videos, games, and additional software..
```

I am not dual booting and for a personal reason I won't change the hdd1 into GPT. And my computer uses SATA. I thought to ask a question here before trying, just in case..

Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows is perfectly capable to understand both MBR and GPT partitioning scheme on different hard disks, regardless of the type it was booted from.

So yes, your GPT /Windows/ (not the hard drive) will be able to read the MBR hard drive. Something like that is constantly done when you plug in a USB key, which also is most of the time partitioned (albeit with only one partition) using MBR.

Comment: ok I see... so on hdd1 (mbr) I can also create some partitions for Linux and then choose the boot media (windows or linux) from UEFI, right?

Comment: Depends on the UEFI implementation. You’d still have to install a bootloader somewhere for Linux (usually on hdd1). Then your UEFI would probably show you the options to boot from:

<UEFI hdd0> (Windows)
<hdd1>  (Linux)
(note that on the 2nd disk, typically, that drive is not recognized as UEFI bootable (hence the other name), but the legacy boot is used instead, simply because no GPT-"EFI System Partition" is present on that disk)

2nd option would be use GPT for the 2nd disk, too.

3rd option would be using the dual boot capacity of the WIndows bootloader (but cumbersome to set up).

Comment: You'll need to install an *EFI-mode* boot loader for Linux. This will usually happen automatically if you boot the installation medium in EFI mode, but some distributions' installers may be confused by the MBR partition table in this case. I recommend you read [my page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) to get a better understanding of the issues involved before proceeding. Knowing what Linux distribution you intend to install may be helpful in providing a better answer, too.